# How to Tie Events to CSS

Tags: css, gwt

In a Google Web Toolkit project, I have a button in a website that's used to track activity. I am asking this question as a maintenance developer without in-depth knowledge of the software that I'm fixing.

I have determined the CSS class name that's used for the image, which is put on a button. When the button is pressed, a user then tracks activity. The CSS is called "trackActivity."

I would like to know what code gets called when that button is pressed.

How could I determine where to find the code that registers code against this particular button, of whose CSS class I'm aware.

Thanks

Comment: CSS doesn't trigger any code. What is MORE likely is that there's JavaScript that's reporting back to a web service on Google's site OR the css points to an image that sits on Google's site.  Google can determine who's hitting the image and use that to track your site's visitors.  It's the same technique email marketing companies use to track email opens - they embed a hidden image link in the email that retreives the image from their server.  More info describing how it works here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219590/mass-email-tracking

Comment: You do not have GWT src code as I understand. Compiled code is usually obfuscated so function will not be very helpful for you. Moreover GWT is not work like JQuery so you will not be able to easily find click handler based on css. GWT use generate id attributes to process events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your new to development perhaps try viewing the source of the page and searching for trackActivity, perhaps the javascript is in-line. If not open the .js files, probably found at the top of the source and search in there. That will likely provide some more info...