# How do i track on email?

Tags: email, tracking, confirmation

How to i know whether the Email sent to my customers is read or not? Is there is any software which does that?
I would like to do some tracking of email, like how many times it is hit, opened etc.

Comment: People can (and usually do) disable notification of their email. And they could fetch an email without really reading it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1219590/139010 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2958926/139010

Comment: Typically most email service providers use a 1x1 pixel image to track opens in email, and they put tracking code into the url's of links to track the clicks. Opens can only be tracked if the user turns on images, there is no way to track opens without images enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to track his email status directly , at best you could request read notifications.

But you could add some html content that is linked back to your site and count from there.
But the other user must enable remote content.