# How to know that an email message was read?

Tags: email, smtp, email-client

I have a software that sends notifications, quotes and invoices to "clients of my clients" by email. Sometimes people don't answer it very fast, so someone needs to call by phone to confirm if they received and get the feedback. I would like to automate this, to know if them, at least, read the email. I know this is very difficult due to how email works, but some companies already try to do this in a satisfactory way, like:

- [mailgun.com](http://www.mailgun.com)
- [mailchimp.com](http://www.mailchimp.com)
- [sendwithus.com](http://www.sendwithus.com) ([YCombinator](http://www.ycombinator.com) funded).

In HTML mail messages we can create a resource that points to the server, like a image. But mail clients usually ask permission to the user to load the images. So, problem 
here.

But for text mail messages? Is there any way to know the email was read? How companies these companies do?

PS: I don't know what tags is the best to classify my answer, I shall appreciate any edit.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  You could always use the Read Receipt feature of your mail client.  However, mail clients are meant to protect the users privacy: unless you can somehow entice the user to follow a link or something, there is no way to know for sure.

Comment: I want my program send an email and notify me when someone open it. I think this is programming question.

Comment: The rest of the answer still stands. :)

Comment: Thanks! So we have the Read Receipt feature and requests for resources (when HTML messages). Right?

Comment: Yes, but neither of these are perfect, for the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: Mail clients ask the user BECAUSE they don't want to cooperate with you. They're loyal to their user, not to you. You're fighting the design.

Comment: Hosted images embedded in the message and read receipts will work some of the time, but not all of the time, for the reasons mentioned above.  Another (slightly more cumbersome) method, which can be used to determine with certainty whether or not the recipient has read the message is to store the message itself as a PDF document on a web server, then send the recipient a secure link to download the PDF document.  This process can be streamlined using UltraSMTP (see www.ultrasmtp.com/resources/documentdeliveryconfirmation.php).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mass email tracking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219590/mass-email-tracking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to be 100% sure if a email was opened, because of its architecture. There are some techniques to do this, but it always depends of user actions and mail client configurations. But:

- For HTML messages you can use images and/or the [return receipts (RFC 3798)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3798).
- For text based messages you can use only the [return receipts (RFC 3798)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3798).

About opening tracking:

> Opens are tracked by including a transparent .png file, which will
> only work if there is an HTML component to the email (i.e., text only
> emails will not track opens). You should note that many email service
> providers disable images by default, so this data will only show up if
> the recipient clicks on display images button in his/her email.
>
> (Text extracted from [mailgun.com](http://mailgun.com) [user docs](http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#tracking-opens))

References:

- [MailGun.com](http://www.mailgun.com) [documentation](http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#tracking-messages).
- Previous discutions on this thread.

Answer (score 1):

As arnt says, you're fighting the design and basic operation of e-mail. Whenever you send a mail, there is a boundary between a MTA you control (or at least have an account on) and a MTA that is responsible for your target user's mail. What you can know is whether the user's MTA accepted the mail for delivery. Whatever happens afterwards is outside of your control.

Consider an example of a snail mail. When the package enters the recipient's box, you won't know whether they put the whole unopened envelope to a trash bin, or whether they opened is and read the contents very carefully. You can approximate that goal by using crude measures (like embedding a webcam-and-a-computer which will activate upon envelope opening and send you the snapshot of the face of the opener via a cell phone), but doing so is unreliable, unethical, and probably illegal in plenty of countries.

The "return receipts" or embedded image links are similar -- because the whole e-mail is already in the hands of the user's SW, they can do anything with it. A good MUA will probably ask before sending out dumb return receipts, and it also won't load remote images in HTML mail (because it's easy to create an http://trackme.example.org/mail/for/user/12345/message/666/image.png and have a database which says "hey, this URL belongs to Mr. Pichler, and is used in the first message we sent him). The most you can do is to ask nicely, and [return receipts (RFC 3798)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3798) are a machine-readable way of doing just that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jan, but I'm not trying to "fight again" anything, maybe I'm not so good with my simple English, but the way you said sounds bad to me. I just have a problem to solve and I know some companies have doing the same, like MailChimp.com, www.sendwithus.com (YCombinator funded), etc.

Comment: My problem is not related to doing any kind of spam, and its related to notifications I sent to customers by email where my client would be very happy if he don't need to spend time calling to his customers checking if they read their email. I was just researching possibilities to automate this. At beginning I thought there was no way to do, but if some great companies do, I thought that maybe I was not aware of some detail.

Comment: I just edited my question to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: There is no way which will work without false positives or false negatives. The best option is probably to use return receipts, see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3798 for how it's done.