# Email open tracking

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, imap, html-email

I have to create email tracking system, but the problem is that when the sender opens an email this is counted as an opening by the recipient.

When I send an email through Polymail (or some other tools for tracking emails), then in the 'sent' folder I have an email without a tracking pixel, but the recipients of this email have the pixel and at the same time everyone have different code inside (I think, to determine which of the recipients opened the email).

How is this possible? The sender and the recipients have different contents of the same email. Can this be implemented using smtp / imap / gmail-api?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mass email tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219590/mass-email-tracking)

Comment: @Syfer This is not the answer to my question. I asked about different content in the same email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For standard IMAP/SMTP setups (specifically: *not* GMail), the message is submitted twice, once to SMTP to be sent, and again to IMAP to be placed in the Sent mailbox.

There is no requirement that these be the same: in fact, in normal use, the BCC header, for example, is submitted to IMAP, but not SMTP.

GMail, and a few others, while trying to be helpful and save bandwidth, do the copy automatically, but make it impossible to supply different versions.  (Unless you want to try to find the duplicates and delete them out of band).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I didn't find any implementation of how to save an email sent via SMTP so that these two emails have the same UID. Could you give me an example (in any language)?

Comment: SMTP messages don't have UIDs, so that doesn't make sense.  If you mean the Message-ID header, then just construct the message with the same Message-ID header, but with the changes you want in the body.  Then use an IMAP library to do an `APPEND`.  There's lots of IMAP sample code out there for APPEND to the sent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Current Email protocols don't send any kind of ACK to the Sender when mail is opened. So you need to put some kind of analytic tool inside the mail contents to keep the track of it. 
Some suggested methods and widely used tool is [Bananatag](https://bananatag.com/email-tracking/). 
Alternatively, you can use custom Google Analytics for the same. Refer here https://dyn.com/blog/tracking-email-opens-via-google-analytics/