# Tracking whether sent mail is read or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, tracking

I have searched many articles and have found some code, but it's not working for me.

My index.aspx.cs page code is:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (checkIfRequested(this.Context.Request))
    {           
        //receiver had already requested the image, hence send back a not modified result
        Response.StatusCode = 304;
        Response.SuppressContent = true;
    }
    else
    {
        int emailId = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["emailId"]) && int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["emailId"], out emailId))
        {
            Session["image"] = Request.QueryString["emailId"];
            lblid.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["image"]);


            //The email with emailId has been opened, so log that in database
        }
        else
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["emailId"] != null)
            {
                lblid.Text = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["emailId"]);
            }
            string str = "<script>alert('empty')</script>";
            Page.RegisterStartupScript("popup", str);
        }

        //Send the single pixel gif image as response
        byte[] imgbytes = Convert.FromBase64String("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAANvf7wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==");
        Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", imgbytes.Length.ToString());
        Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        Response.BinaryWrite(imgbytes);
    }
}

private bool checkIfRequested(HttpRequest req)
{
    // check if-modified-since header to check if receiver has already requested the image in last 24 hours
    return req.Headers["If-Modified-Since"] == null ? false : DateTime.Parse(req.Headers["If-Modified-Since"]).AddHours(24) >= DateTime.Now;
}
```

My index.aspx page seems as:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>   
</form>
</body>
```

I used to send email to my own Gmail id from my aspx page like:

```
String MailContent = "";
MailContent += "<img src='http://WWW.mywebsitename.com/index.aspx?emailId=1' width='1' height='1' />
client = new SmtpClient();
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Myemailidofhmail", "mypassword");
client.Port = 25;
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.EnableSsl = true; 
mailto = "mitesh@gmail.com";
message = MailContent.ToString();
msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(mailto);
```

Here the mail is coming successfully to my Gmail account on `mitesh@gmail.com` id, but when I open that email from my account I am not getting `Request.QueryString["emailId"]` value as 1 to my `index.aspx`

Comment: The single-pixel image scheme for tracking email messages is widely blocked by email clients. Specifically, Gmail serves all images to email users from a proxy server. Your single-pixel scheme simply won't work.

Comment: so what else I have to do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the answers to these questions:

[Is there any way to track whether an email has been opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822862/is-there-any-way-to-track-whether-an-email-has-been-opened)

[Mass email tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219590/mass-email-tracking)

Quote from the answer in the first question:

> Mail clients block pretty much all of these kinds of attempts. The
>   best idea is to give them an image that they would want to see if they
>   read the message, and therefore they choose to display images in their
>   mail client.

So yeah, that's pretty much the best advice, and even then it may not work well if the email client is caching your images (though it should still be able to log the first download). There's no foolproof method of actually verifying if someone's read your email, unless you can make them visit your website with a link in the email.

Comment: @Xtremcool The problem is not with your code, but rather with email clients blocking your image and/or it's call back to your server. If you really need to track your email's status, get your users to click on a link in the email.