# Tracking Email Opens

Tags: html-email

I'm attempting to track email opens to determine whether social health resources are reaching patients who request them. I've briefly read about using utm parameters or tracking pixels, but am unsure of exactly how to do this.

Thanks all.

Comment: There are a number of answers already - did you check these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822862/is-there-any-way-to-track-whether-an-email-has-been-opened https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973143/tracking-email-bounces-opens-clicks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219590/mass-email-tracking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958926/track-mass-email-campaigns
It sounds like you might be trying to code it yourself - what coding stack are you using? Alternatively, what email service provider are you going to use - these will mostly do it for you.

Comment: hi, thanks for the info. I had already looked into these, however, my organization does not yet have a website that it owns. i'm unsure of how to utilize google analytics in our emails. We will be using outlook to reach out to patients with a variety of email providers.

Comment: okay, so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456592/tracking-email-opens-in-google-analytics?